# What happened at the end of Prometheus Movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, prometheus

I watched Prometheus last night. Though I found some good information on Movies.SE, I still have some questions about the movie.

- There were some scenes that picture holographic images. I don't understand how they have enough energy to create holographs
- What happened to Dr. Shaw at the end? Was she able to return to Earth or she was stuck on the same planet?
- Why did the engineer want to destroy Humanity? And since he had no weapons, how could he have destroyed  all of Humanity on Earth with a single space craft?

Comment: the first question is a bit odd, why would the energy be relevant? It's a sci fi movie, just assume that everyone has tools that store/generate great power out of thin air

Comment: There are similar questions to your (2) and (3): [The ending in Prometheus](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8660/the-ending-in-prometheus) and [What was the motivation behind the Engineers actions in Prometheus?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2748/what-was-the-motivation-behind-the-engineers-actions-in-prometheus)

Comment: I too do not understand the first question.  How are they able to travel across interstellar distances and not take centuries and carry vast amounts of fuel as well?  Science fiction requires some ability to suspend disbelief.

Comment: With the potential amount of content this question brings, I'd almost recommend asking it as separate questions, but that is my own opinion.

Comment: I don't think Major Stackings and Sahil Mahajan MJ watched or listened to this movie carefully enough. All of those questions were answered by the dialogue and action in the movie. As far as the technological questions go, the story did start in the year of 2091! JS...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prometheus did pose some interesting questions, so here goes:

1. What makes you think the holograms take a lot of energy? They're on a ship that's travelled "billions of miles" from Earth; running a few holographic generators (small ones at that) shouldn't pose a problem.
2. Shaw took David's head and used it to commandeer another ship, heading out to find more answers (presumably the Engineer's homeworld).
3. A single vial of the "black liquid" virus would probably be enough to wipe out all life on Earth. [See this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2748/what-was-the-motivation-behind-the-engineers-actions-in-prometheus) for a thorough look at the Engineer's motivation.

Comment: Yes, good points, specialle the 3rd one.

Answer (score 3):

> There were some scenes that picture holographic images. I don't get from where they were getting that much energy to create holographs.

[image]

David inspects writing on the wall, and rubs off some kind of gel with his fingers. When he inspects the gel he sees glowing specks of organic life in the gel. A kind of living digital storage that lines the walls of the cave.

He activates the writing on the wall and the specks in the gel turn on to play back the old recording that we see as the *hologram*. It's not really a holographic image as much as it is a recording saved into the living gel that lines the walls. This is why the images are made up on glowing dots that look a lot like the dots in the gel.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1) When you have a ship blasting an interstellar quad engine layout I'd imagine hololithics would be relatively easy from a power consumption point of view.

2) She wasn't going back to earth, in fact she explicitly states she intends to find the Engineer home world and then you see her take off in another spacecraft.

3) a) Welcome to a main plot thread of the whole movie.
   b) Are you sure you watched this? The cargo hold is packed with canisters of the virulent evolutionary biological weapon.